# Inifinite loop not printing all values

Tags: c++, coding-style, turbo-c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{   
    clrscr();
    int a,b;
    a=0;
    cin>>b;
    do
    {
    if (b==1)
        cout<<"case1a " ;
    else if (b==2)
        cout<<"case 1b ";
        a=a+1;
    }
    while(a=0);

    cout<<"Interval";

    do
    {
    if (b==1)
        cout<<"case 2a";
    else if (b==2)
        cout<<"case 2b";
        a=a-1;
    }
    while(a=1);

    getch();
}
```

The above code creates an infinite loop.
The expected output is "case1a case2a case3a case4a" infinite times but the program only prints "case1a" infinite times

So how can i correct this and get my desired output?

<strike>PS i used shift+break to pause the output to see whats being printed on the screen</strike>

Comment: Indent your code properly so that it's readable.

Comment: @Chemistpp - there is a 'using namespace std', it's just tabbed off the screen at the top :)

Comment: @Chemistpp He is using an old compiler which doesnt use `std::`

Comment: @MartinJames Didn't see it. I copied/pasted into vs studio to fix the formatting.  Figured it was a improper } by default from that mess.  Okay, I delete my comment since I guess that is not so important.

Comment: I can't see where you output `case3a` or `case4a`... it also doesn't look very infinite to me at the moment, even accounting for the typo in the `while`. Are you sure this is the program you're running?

Comment: @MartinJames I didn't get it. (Sorry, if I am missing some sarcasm :P) Where is `namespace std` used? I didn't see it.

Comment: @VusP: Indeed it does, but not the first loop, which is where `case1a` is output... from what I can tell this happens only once (`a=0` evaluates to `0`, or false).

Answer (score 3):

`while(a=0)` should be `while(a==0)`

Likewise for your 2nd `while`.

You are confusing the assignment operator `=` with the equality operator `==`.

Comment: ok i just changed = with == now the problem is that its no longer a infinite loop... where as i want a infinite loop thats why i did a=a+1 in first loop and a=a-1 in second loop to make it a infinite loop..

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do...  I know it involves an infinite loop, but beyond that...

Comment: @user2891112  Why would that make an infinite loop?  After the first loop is completed nothing in your code goes back to it.  The second loop isn't setup to loop forever by itself.

Answer (score 0):

no semi colon ( ; ) after while statement.

Comment: it would be a more clear answer if you could include a bit of the code and in it, show how you would fix it.